# Sphinx autosummary: dataclass inheritance

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autosummary

Following code makes Sphinx autosummary fail:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: int


class FooChild(Foo):
    pass
```

My autosummary template (`_templates/autosummary/class.rst`):

```
{{ name | escape | underline}}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. autoclass:: {{ objname }}
   :members:

   {% block attributes %}
   {% if attributes %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Attributes') }}

   .. autosummary::
   {% for item in attributes %}
      ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
```

When running `sphinx-build -j 2 -W -b html docs docs/gh-pages` I get following warning:

```
Warning, treated as error:
~/path/docs/generated/module.FooChild.rst:14:autosummary: 
failed to import FooChild.bar.
```

I need to treat warnings as errors because otherwise documentation in my project will quickly degrade, but I would like to either fix root cause of this one or ignore this specific warning.

I couldn't find any way to ignore a warning from source code comments, nor to selectively suppress warnings from Sphinx configuration. Please help!

EDIT:
here is what generated `FooChild.rst` file looks like:

```
FooChild
========
.. currentmodule:: package.module

.. autoclass:: FooChild
   :members:

   .. rubric:: Attributes
   .. autosummary::
      ~FooChild.bar
```

I have a `conf.py` adding `api.rst` to toctree, `api.rst` is designed to trigger autosummary to create documentation for all modules and classes, in this example just `module.py`.

```
API Overview
************

.. currentmodule:: package
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated
   :recursive:

   module
```

Comment: This is an import error and Sphinx cannot find your module. What is the path in your `conf.py`? Do you have an `__init__.py` file in your module's directory? What is in your `module.FooChild.rst`?

Comment: @StevePiercy I do have `__init__.py`, and the same error occurs with or w/o having Foo and FooChild imported there. I don't have `module.FooChild.rst`, it's generated by autosummary extension. I've added generated file at the end of my question, as well as info about conf.py and autosummary entry point.

Comment: Note that without FooChild, documentation is successfully generated and contains class Foo, so I think there is no problem with paths setup.

Comment: Does it work if you change `~FooChild.bar` to just `~bar`?

Comment: This file is generated, it's overwritten if I modify it to ~bar.

Comment: But can't you update the autosummary template?

Comment: yes, I can change `~{{ name }}.{{ item }}` to `~{{ item }}`, this leads to error changing to `module.Foo.rst:13:autosummary: failed to import bar.`

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't fix the root cause, but you asked for a way to ignore this warning:

You could add `__all__` to your module, that doesn't include `FooChild`. This way it will be ignored by autosummary.

From documentation `autosummary_ignore_module_all` https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html:

> If False and a module has the `__all__` attribute set, autosummary documents every member listed in `__all__` and no others. Default is True

> Note that if an imported member is listed in `__all__`, it will be documented regardless of the value of autosummary_imported_members. To match the behaviour of from module import *, set autosummary_ignore_module_all to False and autosummary_imported_members to True.

> New in version 4.4.